# Google Sheets extract string after a certain part of word

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a regular expression that will extract a word from a certain cell. The word starts with st and I would like to extract all the word up to the next space.

I have this so far: =MID(C3,FIND("st",C3),15) but I would prefer to have it extract to the next space, not guess how long the word is.

Comment: Post few sample data and show desired output.

Comment: Sample data: Seagate
S/N: 5QZ3CK32
ST380815AS
P/N: 9CY131-276
Firmware: 3.CCA

result I am after:
ST380815AS

Comment: Data is in cell C3

Comment: fantastic. Just what I was after. Is there a way for this to discover words that start with ST and a number instead of a letter? e.g. find ST380815AS, not STOP (If it had "STOP " in C3)?

Comment: I have tried =REGEXEXTRACT(C1770,"ST\d+"), but  the end of the word ends in letters, and it does not extract the AS at the end. I still would like to extract the whole word, but only words that start in ST(number).....

Comment: Then you may give atry to `=REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"ST\d+\w")`.

Comment: That worked great. I just had to add a + after w so that it picked up the last letter.
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"ST\d+\w+")

Comment: Glad to know. If it helps then please accept my answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Comment: I have done so, but it will only show once I have 15 points. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXEXTRACT()` function.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"ST\w+")
```

[image]

Comment: Check this article https://productivityspot.com/regexextract-google-sheets/.